# $(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)\cap\mathbb Q$ is not compact

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

> How to show that $(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)\cap\mathbb Q$ is not compact in $\mathbb Q$ even though it's closed and bounded in $\mathbb Q$.

Second part is easy. Please help me to show that $(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)\cap\mathbb Q$ is not compact.

Comment: Take $q_n$ in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}$ converging to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Consider the open cover given by $A_n=(-\sqrt 2+1/n,\sqrt 2-1/n)\cap\Bbb Q$, $n=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: Closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$ implies compact, the set you are asking about is clearly bounded but it is not close, take the sequence julien mentioned.

Comment: @i.a.m The OP surely meant the relative topology. Then $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}=[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is indeed closed in the latter. The sequence I mentioned was just to show that not every sequence admits a converging subsequence in that space.

Comment: @julien, Oh, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume the standard topology on $\mathbb{Q}$. As julien and David pointed out some possible ways to prove that the set is not compact. In fact using the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, that the Intersection of any non trivial intervall (one which does have more than $1$ element) with $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be compact in $\mathbb{Q}$. The main idea is using that you can find for every irrational number a sequence of rational numbers converging to it (for example take the decimal expansion).

For a metric space we know that a set is compact if every sequence does have a convergent subsequence. And a sequence which converges to an irrational number in $\mathbb{R}$ won't converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The exercise itself refers to the Theorem of Heine Borel which states that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which states that the compact sets are the closed and bounded one.

Comment: The wording of the question is slightly ambiguous, but it can easily be interpreted to mean closed in $\mathbb Q$, which is true.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @SritiMallick edited my answer hope it is more helpfull now

Answer (score 4):

Heine-Borel theorem holds in $\mathbb{R}$, not in subspaces thereof. If a subspace $A$ of the metric space $X$ is compact (with the relative topology), then it is closed in $X$, because any sequence in $A$ has a cluster point. So, if a sequence in $A$ converges to some $x\in X$, and $x\notin A$, the sequence has *no* cluster point in $A$, hence $A$ is not compact.

Since $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, it is not compact. Just consider an increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But doesn't this show it isn't compact in R? How can we say whether it is compact in Q or not?

Answer (score 0):

take the sequence {1+1/1!+1/2!+...+1/n!-2} in this set converging to e-2,which does not belong to this set.